# Regex to match consecutive tags ignoring text between them

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have a custom tag of Part of speech. I want to check if they are consecutive.
My string is

```
 <pronouns></pronouns><pronouns></pronouns><verbs></verbs><determiners></determiners><noun></noun>
```

Eg. If i use this regex `(<pronouns><\/pronouns>)\1{1}` it gives me two pronoun tags consecutively

```
**<pronouns></pronouns><pronouns></pronouns>**<verbs></verbs><determiners></determiners><noun></noun>
```

and if i use this regex  `(<pronouns><\/pronouns><verb><\/verb>)\1{0}`
it gives me one occurrence of pronoun and verb tag and if i modify it to `(<pronouns><\/pronouns><verb><\/verb>)\1{1}` it will give me two consecutive occurrence of pronoun and verb tag.
Problem is this if there is any text between the tag it fails to match if it is consecutive

```
<pronouns>Hello</pronouns><pronouns>Hi</pronouns><pronouns>Hi</pronouns><verbs>Ok</verbs><determiners>the</determiners><noun>people</noun>
```

match fails for above if you use Previous Regex.

How can I match the regex with text with the previous conditions and also get the text captured between the consecutive tags tags.

Comment: This is somewhat unclear, please clarify what output you want to get. Try `(<pronouns>(.*?)<\/pronouns>)\g<1>`. What text in between tags do you need to match? Both `Hi` and `Hello` in `<pronouns>Hello</pronouns><pronouns>Hi</pronouns>`? What is the regex flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated - this isn't crystal clear... But if I understand it correctly you want to match if there are two consecutive pair of `pronoun`-tags, no matter what their text content is.

If that's correct, you could try

```
(?:<(pronouns)>.*?<\/\1>){2}
```

It matches the first `pronoun`-tag, capturing the the name. Then it matches any text up to the closing tag. Matches that and then repeats the same pattern again.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gR0oT5/4).

Comment: This is what i expected but the issue is it doesn't capture repentance if i want a pronoun and verb repentance. My old regex (<pronouns><\/pronouns><verbs></verbs>)\1{1} does that. How can i modify you regex to achieve the above